# Compiling libogg using Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, ogg

I've just downloaded libogg from http://www.xiph.org/downloads/ (http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/ogg/libogg-1.3.0.tar.gz) and I'm now trying to compile the Ogg.xcodeproj project provided in that package.  When I try to build, I get the following error:

> The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme 'Ogg'.
>
> The scheme 'Ogg' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64-bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.

I get a similar error if I attempt to build the static library instead of the framework:

> The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme 'libogg (static)'.
>
> The scheme 'libogg (static)' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64-bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.

Again, this is just opening the project in Xcode 4.3.2 for the first time and attempting to build.  I've made no changes to the project file at all.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution to get this to compile?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the Xcode project was linking against an old SDK on an old architecture (OS X 10.5 PPC, whereas I have OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion x64).

To fix this in Xcode 5, select the top-level project in Xcode (the top-most node in the project folder pane, with the blue "A" icon) followed by the Project. Change **Architectures** to something suitable for your current system, such as **Native Architecture of Build machine** and change **Base SDK** to an SDK currently installed in your Xcode environment, such as **OS X 10.8**.

Here is a screenshot of my project to help you find those settings (following the highlighted parts: **kisshelper** > **kisshelper** > **Architectures**):

[image]